# C++ Function Pointer (Callback) without Inheritance

Tags: c++, events, callback, function-pointers

I am working on an Input Event system where I have very flexible use of what to do when specific input happens without polling. I am using SDL for gathering input so you will see some SDL events.

I plan on doing all this by "binding" an event (Keypress) to a function. I want this to work for any class that has an instance of my InputManager.

This is what I have right now for the InputManger class:

```
//InputManager.h

typedef void (*Callback)();
typedef std::unordered_map<SDL_Keycode, Callback> KeyCode;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCode> Binding;

class InputManager {
public:
    void bindInput(EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback f);
    void updateInput(SDL_Event event);
private:
    Binding inputBindings;
};

...

//InputManager.cpp

void InputManager::bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback f)
{
    inputBindings[eventType][key] = f;
}

void InputManager::updateInput(SDL_Event event)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (inputBindings[event.type][event.key.keysym.sym])
            //Exists call function here
    }
}
```

This is what an example would look like of binding a key to a function:

```
//A.cpp

//This function will be called when the class is being initialized
void init(InputManager* m_InputManager) {
    m_InputManager->bindInput(SDL_KEYDOWN, keypress_A, &A::testFunction);
}

//This is the callback function when A is pressed
void testFunction() {
    //Do stuff
}
```

My problem is that it wont take any member (A). The actual error code is
`Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Callback' (aka 'void (*)()') with an rvalue of type 'void (A::*)()'`

Now I interpret this as I have to specify (in the InputManager) for it to take (A::*). The problem is that I want any class given InputManager the ability to use this and the InputManager shouldn't have access to any of the other classes (A in this case).

What I have tried:

The first thought that came to my mind would be templates. I am not that experienced with them so they could still be the answer but I failed with them. Since the Callback function is defined in a typedef, I couldn't apply the template directly. This is what it ended up looking like:

```
template <class T>
struct Callback {
    typedef void (T::*F)();
};

template <class T>
struct KeyCodeStruct {
    typedef std::unordered_map<SDL_Keycode, Callback<T>> KeyCode;
};

template <class T>
struct BindingStruct {
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCodeStruct<T>> Binding;
};

class InputManager {
public:
    template <class T>
    void bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback<T> f);
    void updateInput(SDL_Event event);
private:
    template <class T>
    BindingStruct<T> inputBindings; //This is the area where I loose my grip on a template.
    //^^^ Member 'inputBindings' declared as a template
};
```

After this error I was essentially putting things I probably shouldn't into templates and doing things I didn't understand at all. I figured it would be better to just ask. I have read loads of things on function pointers and maybe the answer is simple and I just can't seem to understand it so maybe try defining it for me in Layman's terms?

**Edit:**

Also, I should add that I plan on distributing my InputManager throughout my whole project and the reason I put without Inheritance in the title is because I read a solution where you have a base class that all other files inherent from. I really can't do this on a large scale project. If that is the only way of going about that I may end up doing it but I will probably just stick with polling then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

The problem is that `Callback` is defined as a pointer to a function returning void, and your binding attempt is using  `&A::testFunction` which is a pointer to a member function of class A.

Pointer to a function can be called without further requirement.  But pointer to a member function of a class need to be called for an object x (or a pointer to an object) of the right class:

```
(x.*f)();    // call member function with object of the right member class
```

The problem with your template approach,  is that you need to store for a binding, not only the pointer to member function,  but also a pointer to an object of type T,  so that you could call the function for an object.

**The solution**

There is an elegant solution using [`<functional>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/)  which permits to store a [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) and a binding.  This works also for a [binding](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) between a member function and an object of a suitable class.

Here a small demo of the concept, up to you to adapt it for your need:

```
class Test {     // function with a callback for demo of proof of concept 
public:
    void myfct() {
        cout << "Myfct !!\n";
    }
}; 

class Manager {    // Simplified manager
    std::function <void()> f;    // this is the trick !! 

public: 
    template <class T>
    void binding(T *object, void (T::*mf)()) {
        f = std::bind(mf, object);   // you bind the member function to the object it has to be used with 
    }
    void testcall() {     // Just for showing the proof of concept 
        f(); 
    }
};
```

You can then try this with:

```
Manager man; 
Test tst; 

man.binding(&tst, &Test::myfct); 
man.testcall();
```

Comment: So your saying that I have to use the template method? What about the error I get?

Comment: I was just editing the solution, see updated answer.  It builds up on your clever idea of using a templatized binding function. About your error, `Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Callback' (aka 'void (*)()')` says that your callback is defined to be a "normal" function.   It `with an rvalue of type 'void (A::*)()'`  means that your tried to assing a pointer to a member function of class A.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm on the right track now. Is the `function` you use the std::function?

Comment: Exactly, `std::function` !

Comment: Alright, I'll accept after I get it working. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still stuck on the template part where I define inputBindings. It still doesn't work. I'm not quite sure what to do there.